# DB Certificates

Tags: oracle

I hope this is the right place to as this question.

I just earned a Bachelor's degree in Management Information Systems and I'm interested in becoming a Database Admin. However, I'm a little confused on how to go about this without experience in the field. Do DB certificates hold any weight in the field? Would you recommend getting something like your Oracle OCA/OCP?

If you do recommend something like the Oracle OCP, do you have any study materials you could recommend?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`Short answer:`

Get some hands-on experience first and worry about certifications later.

`A bit longer thoughts:`

Certifications are just cherry on the top. But you have to bake the cake first. They mean nothing if you do not have any real life experience. But when you have - they give you a bit of an advantage in your job interview.

Also do not concentrate just on Oracle. Most DBAs are qualified in several databases. Start with MySQL, PostgreSQL. They are simplier to start but still the core principles are the same. Also it should be much easier to find some real life practice with those databases. Then continue climbing the ladder.

Good luck!